# How to match before parenthesis with lookahead

Tags: regex

I have this:

```
aaa(bbb)
```

Which I match `(bbb)` using this:

```
\(.*?\)
```

I now wish to match `aaa` so I tried a 'positive lookahead assertion'. This does not work.

```
(\(.*?\))(?=\()
```

How can i match the letters before the `(`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply using `^[^(]*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one,

```
   .*(?=\()
```

RegexBuddy ScreenShot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you don't actually need a lookahead. You can just use `[^(]*` to match everything preceding the first `(`

```
^([^(]*)
```

To get that and the contents of the `()`, add you exsiting `(.*?)` capture group.

```
^([^(]*)\((.*?)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply match `/(aaa)(\(bbb\))/` and then referring to your matches with `$1` and `$2`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(\(.*?\))(?=\()
 ^^  ^^
```

These enforce the "aaa" to be enclosed in brackets (after whom shell come a opening bracket). You seem to want

```
/(.+?)(?=\(.*?\))/
```